# how to draw string to an image from left bottom corner to right upper corner

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphics, system.drawing

Here is my code:

```
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);

  var myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(32, 205, 205, 205));
   g.DrawString(label, new Font("verdana", 10, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), myBrush, 10,10);
```

It doesn't work very well about put the string on the image. This code can write very well but   I couldn't put the string from left buttom corner to right upper corner. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Would setting a background image of the button work instead?

Comment: @krillgar, I don't understand what are you asking but I just want to put a string to all my images. I can put sting but it is like a line on Y axis. I want to write it 45-degree angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g.RotateTransform(45f);
```

and only after that

```
g.DrawString(label, new Font("verdana", 10, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), myBrush, 10,10);
```

But that would only rotate by 45 degrees. Depending on size of your button and length of your text which can be calculated using `MeasureString` method, you will need to adjust the angle and position of the text. I hope you like geometry.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform(v=vs.100).aspx

In order to move the position where the string is drawn, you'll need to use the TranslateTransform(dx,dy) method of your graphics object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4(v=vs.100).aspx

So to draw string in center, you'd call translate then rotate then draw. If that doesn't work well try changing the order of rotate and translate.

Comment: At first, I wrote wrong and my question title edited. It should be bottom corner. Yes RotateTransform do it very well and thank you for it but how can I put my string middle of my image? Do you have idea?

Comment: @cagin added a reference on how to change the position to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you find an image of a diagonal line (which shouldn't be hard), just set the Button's background image property to the image. The code for it is similar to this:

`button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img2));`

I believe there are properties to set for stretching the image and stuff in case it doesn't quite line up properly.